# Linear extention of unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have a Real Hilbert space $H$ and an operator $\beta$ over $H$ satisfyng $\beta^{\ast}=-\beta$ and $\beta^2=-1$  (this easily implies $\beta$ would be unitary).

Now I consider the complixification of $H$ call it $H_{\mathbb{C}}$ and extend $\beta$ by linearity to $H_{\mathbb{C}}$ and call the extention $\beta_{\mathbb{C}}$. So my question is the following ¿Is $\beta_{\mathbb{C}}$ instead unitary? ¿or satisfies the aforementiones equalities?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there's no problem, complexification is defined so that it preserves all of the relevant structure here.

Comment: Thanks! can you give me some idea of the proof?

Comment: You want to check that complexification sends composition to composition, $-1$ to $-1$, and adjoint to adjoint. All of these are very straightforward. You may want to take $H = \mathbb{R}^n$ first with the standard inner product so that things are as clear as possible.

Comment: Thanks!! I have just done the computations.